# Multitenant PR Status Server - Authentication & Authorization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to build an azure devops pull request status server as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server?view=azure-devops). The pr status server works together with an azure devops extension.

Ideally, the pr status server multi-tenant aware (i.e. server multiple azure devops organizations owned by completely different businesses) but i don't quite grok how the authentication would work.

The pr server needs the ability to write the PR statuses for different orgs. Is it possible to perform the client credential flow against multiple orgs? Or use Managed Identity somehow?

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!